# Jetbains Rider remote debugging ASP.NET Core 6.0 apps through SSH kept failing

Tags: asp.net, debugging, rider

I am trying to remote debug via ssh on an ubuntu host at Ali with no success. I'm using the the latest Rider, 2022.1 EAP 10.

The error is:

> Debugger worker was not initialized within 100,000 ms

I’m running Ubuntu 20.04 64bit on Ali Cloud. And one side note: for the following steps from Jetbrains [documents](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/SSH_Remote_Debugging.html#deployment-remote-debug-tools), I wasn’t able to succeed:

```
cd /[application path]/WebApplication to go to the application root folder.

chmod +x ./WebApplication to add the executable bit if needed.

ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000 ./WebApplication to run the application
```

`WebApplication` is a directory, the OS kept complaining it's a directory even after `chmod+x`. I managed to run the self-contained executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to ask such questions in JetBrains public issue tracker.

This problem should already be fixed in the next Rider versions:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-76083

Comment: thx for the advice, i've posted an issue there, hope they would help